# BufferedRead stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader

I am doing a class project that is supposed to read a .txt file and have the program also replace some text. But after I run the code it just constantly runs in a loop and only reading one line of the text. Not really sure what I did wrong but I think it's the reader part of my code.

```
public class FormLetter
{
final static int MAX_LINES = 20;
final static int NUM_INSERTIONS = 4;

String[] formLetter = new String[MAX_LINES];
int lines = 0;


   public static void main(String[] args)

  {
 
  FormLetter letter1 = new FormLetter("formLetter..txt");

  FormLetter letter2 = new FormLetter("longLetter.txt");

  FormLetter letter3 = new FormLetter("formLetter.txt");

  letter3.generateLetter("insertions.txt");
  
}

public FormLetter(String formFileName)
{
  Scanner formFileIn;                        
  String line;
  Path file = Paths.get("H:\\Eclipse\\Programming Project 1\\formLetter.txt");
  InputStream input = null;                     

  try
  {
     formFileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader(formFileName));
     while (lines < MAX_LINES && formFileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
      input = Files.newInputStream(file);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
      Charset.defaultCharset();
      line = reader.readLine();
      System.out.println(line);
     }

     if (formFileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
        System.out.println("File " + formFileName + " is too large to process.\n");
     }
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
  {
     System.out.println("Cannot open " + formFileName + "\n");
  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {
     System.out.println("Error reading from file" + formFileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you wanted a `lines++;` in the loop. What is the purpose of `formFileIn`? You never use it to read anything. Your loop has two terminating conditions, and you use neither of them.

Comment: Well, you successfully confused yourself by using two different readers to read from the same file, but use them separately while reading. Reader `formFileIn` is used to check if there are lines to read, but you actually read them from `file`/`reader` which doesn't affect `formFileIn`. You need to remove one of the readers.

Comment: Thank you Tom for breaking the issue down for me. I'm still very new to this but I managed to get it working when you pointed out that I used two readers. Thanks again!

Comment: That's good to hear. Feel free to post an answer with your corrected code so future readers can learn from it.

Comment: `Charset.defaultCharset();` does nothing. Was that supposed to be passed to the constructor of `InputStreamReader()`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments I was using two readers by mistake causing an infinite loop. I removed the second reader and during my loop now only put to output the next line from the file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class FormLetter
{
   final static int MAX_LINES = 20;
   final static int NUM_INSERTIONS = 4;

   String[] formLetter = new String[MAX_LINES];
   int lines = 0;      

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      FormLetter letter1 = new FormLetter("formLetter..txt");
      FormLetter letter2 = new FormLetter("longLetter.txt");
      FormLetter letter3 = new FormLetter("formLetter.txt");
      letter3.generateLetter("insertions.txt");
      
   } 

   public FormLetter(String formFileName)
   {
     
      Scanner formFileIn;                      
      String line;

      try
      {
         formFileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("H:\\Eclipse\\Programming Project 1\\formLetter.txt"));
         while (lines < MAX_LINES && formFileIn.hasNextLine())
         {
         System.out.println(formFileIn.next());
         } 

         if (formFileIn.hasNextLine())
         {
            System.out.println("File " + formFileName + " is too large to process.\n");
         }
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
      {
         System.out.println("Cannot open " + formFileName + "\n");
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {
         System.out.println("Error reading from file" + formFileName);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I mentioned it once already, but `while (lines < MAX_LINES` - you need to modify `lines` **in** the loop for that to do anything.